# Sound permissions not persisting after reboot

Tags: sound, permissions, pulseaudio, acl

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04

I am having an issue with sound. It seems to be a permissions problem.

When I use the command below sound works with no problems.

```
sudo setfacl -m u:lt:rw /dev/snd/*
```

The problem is I have to do the command every time I reboot.

Any way of making this change persist?